# $(document).ready(function(){alert()}) not working in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

Hey everyone I am facing problem executing the following jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Hello");
})
```

But if I just write alert("Hello") then its working

```
alert("Hello"); //Working
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: Where you put your document.ready?

Comment: No I don't get any errors

Comment: I put it in <script></script> code in same ctp file.

Comment: Where are you including jQuery lib file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have jquery file or CDN

Comment: He says he isn't getting errors in the console. Missing jQuery should trigger some *ReferenceError: $ is not defined* or similar error. (Of course, he could be just lying about errors ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try add `;` after your closing bracket `})`

Comment: There is no need for ;

Comment: in case there's more scripts below that, likely ; is necessary